# Sum of order $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{(n+2)2^{n}}$

Tags: summation

i need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is : Find the sum of order

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{(n+2)2^{n}}$$

I'm not asking anyone to do my task, I need a hint on how to start, because I don't know how to start

Comment: I don't need convergence, I just need the sum of this order.

Comment: “Order”? You mean just the regular sum of the whole thing, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean the regular sum of the order.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what “order” means; I’ve never seen it used in the context of infinite series! Anyway - do the partial sums appear to converge to anything?

Comment: You can use $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots$ and then use some combination of differentiation, integration, and multiplication and division by $x$ applied to both sides to get something like your series and then set  $x=\frac12$

Comment: You could use a partial fraction decomposition as well, instead of one of the answers excellent log expansion, if you find that easier

Comment: Perhaps you mean the order of the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Adding and subtracting one ($n+1=n+2-1$) yields
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (n+1)}{(n+2)2^{n}}&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+2)2^n}
\end{align}
$$
Let $x=-\frac12$.

- The first term of the right hand side is of the form $$g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}x^n$$
- The second term on the right-hand side is of the form $$\begin{align}f(x)&=\sum^n_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n+2}=x^{-2}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}\\
  &=x^{-2}\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n} - x-\frac{x^2}{2}\Big)\\
  &=x^{-2}\Big(-\log(1-x)-x-\frac{x^2}{2}\Big)
  \end{align}$$

Comment: When dividing the sum, why does the counter go from 1?

Comment: This is just  standard re-indexing: $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}=\sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac{x^n}{n}$. The rest is just adding (and subtracting) terms to get the complete well known series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n}=-\log(1-x)$